# Input stream reader- read method return wrong value

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

This may sound very easy or an old stupid question, but it is quite different for me.
I have written a Program for a half-Descending pyramid Pattern which is like this.

1

1   2

1   2   3

1   2   3   4

1   2   3   4   5

I know this is very easy, the trick is I don't wanna do this by use of `Scanner` and `Integer.parseInt()`. I am trying to do this with `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader`.
So when I execute the following code of my main method with a input of 5 in num. It reads it as 53 when I print it. I have no idea why it's happening. But when I use the 'Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())' method it gives the exact output. How is it supposed to happen when read method is supposed to read int values. Please clear it.

```
    int num1;   
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter hte value of num1");
    //num1=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    num1=br.read();
    System.out.println(num1);
    for(int i=0;i<num1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(j+"\t");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

It's my first question so please ignore the silly mistakes, I have tried to write it as best as I could.
Thanks..

Comment: Not a huge deal, but it might help to show your output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It reads it as 53 when i prints it.

Yes, it would. Because you're calling `read()` which returns a single character, or -1 to indicate the end of data.

The character '5' has Unicode value 53, so that's what you're seeing. (Your variable is an `int`, after all.) If you cast `num1` to a `char`, you'll see '5' instead.

When you want to convert the *textual representation* of an integer into an *integer value*, you would usually use code such as `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: omg jon skeet.. I have heard lot about you, and also read too many of your beautiful and amazing answers. Thanks again for a clear and short reply.
So just want to confirm again, there is only one way now to do this by  using Integer.parseInt(readLine())?

Comment: @user2194800: Well, it depends on what you're trying to do. If you *really* only want to read a single character, you can use `read()` and then maybe use `Character.digit`. But then that won't handle values like "10"...

Comment: and i am sorry, i am not eligible to upvote the answer. When i'll get the reputation to do it, i'll surly do that. :)

Comment: @user2194800: You may not be able to upvote, but you can *accept* an answer by clicking on the tickbox beneath the score. (That's not to say you necessarily should accept my answer, but that's how you'd do it :)

Comment: Yes I will surly do that. But according to the stack rule i can't do that for next 2 minuts more. :(

Answer (score 1):

Bufferreader will read unicode value you need to convert it in a int by using:

Integer.parseInt(num1)
 or
Character.getNumericValue(num1)

Answer (score 1):

53 is ASCII for '5', convert the ASCII to print out the correct string.